# SQL query: Trying to create data as a column with the values based on another column. No Pivot or Subquery

Tags: sql

I have been trying to create a new table based on another table. I have an issue with finding the appropriate query to make data from one column be a new field and have that be based on another column. **NOTE**: I cant use pivot or select sub-queries.

The existing table looks like this:

```
+----------+--------------+------------+
| ID       | TYPE         | TYPE_VALUE |
+----------+--------------+------------+
| 001      | start_date   | 2012-04-08 |
| 001      | account      | 4654321    |
| 001      | order_amount | 231        |
+----------+--------------+------------+
```

It should look something like this:

```
+-----+------------+--------------+---------+
| ID  | start_date | order_amount | account |
+-----+------------+--------------+---------+
| 001 | 2012-04-08 |          231 | 4654321 |
+-----+------------+--------------+---------+
```

Please not that there are n amount of columns.

The script I have used looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE table2
SELECT id,type, type_value 
CASE
    WHERE type ='start_date' then type_value,
CASE
    WHERE type ='account' then type_value
CASE
    WHERE type ='order_amount' then type_value
         FROM table1
```

The problem with this I wend up with a table that looks like this:

```
+-----+------------+--------------+---------+
| ID  | start_date | order_amount | account |
+-----+------------+--------------+---------+
| 001 | 2012-04-08 | NULL         | NULL    |
| 001 | NULL       | 231          | NULL    |
| 001 | NULL       | NULL         | 4654321 |
+-----+------------+--------------+---------+
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looking at your final table, I'd try adding a "group by ID" and use max(start_date), max(order_amount), max(account) to combine all data to one row.

Comment: Please replace the `sql` tag with a tag specific to your DBMS, e.g. mysql, sql-server, oracle, etc.

Comment: the query tool i use (internal company one, which is a mix of many RDBMS) does not have the ability to use pivot or the select (select..) commands. also i did have a group by originally just forgot to add one. I think the max would definitely help.

Comment: Sorry about not providing the necessary info. Im a noob to the forum (and to sql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a class pivot idiom:

```
create table table2
select id,
       max(case when type = 'start_date' then type_value end) start_date,
       max(case when type = 'order_amount' then type_value end) order_amount,
       max(case when type = 'account' then type_value end) account
from table1
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the point of the exercise is to get you to learn about self-joins.  Try:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 AS
  SELECT t1.ID,
         t1.TYPE_VALUE AS START_DATE,
         t2.TYPE_VALUE AS ACCOUNT
    FROM TABLE1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 t2
      ON (t2.ID = t1.ID)
    WHERE t1.TYPE = 'start_date' AND
          t2.TYPE = 'account'
```

I have confidence you can work it out from there.

Share and enjoy.